# How to add 2nd array for the relation so that the chatbot asks about the relation from the 2nd array?

Tags: python, chatbot

I would like to add in the chatbot a new topic to ask to the user. Something like: If I say this "I am feeling happy" then the chatbot will ask "Why you're happy" and the next answer will come from the user: "Becuase my brother gave me an opportunity." and the chatbot will ask "what's your brother name""

I have tried to add a new array as relation, but It didn't work out.

```
import random

class simplechatbot:

    def run(self):

        welcome = "Hi, what you want to talk about?"
        goodbye = "goodbye"
        feelings = ["afraid", "sick", "stressed", "happy", "unhappy"]
#         relation = ["father", "mother", "sister", "brother"]   # I want to add this also to interact 
        dummy_sentences = [
            "say something about it",
            "Interesting",
            "I didn't get it, could you please explain",
            "what do you think about it?"
        ]

        # Greet the user
        print(welcome);


        # Process user input. Processing continues until the user says goodbye. 
        s = ""
        while s != goodbye:
            # Read user input
            s = input()
#             s = s.lower()

            if s == goodbye:
                print(goodbye);
                break
            answer = ""
            # Check for feelings
            for feeling in feelings:
#                 for relation in relation:
                if feeling in s:
                    # Found feeling -> generate answer
                    answer = "Why you are feeling " + feeling + "?"
                        # stop processing user input
                    break;
#                     elif relation in s:
#                         answer = "what's the name of your", relation, "?"
#                         # stop processing user input
#                         break;

            # If no feeling has been detected, generate a dummy answer.
            if len(answer) == 0:
                # output random sentence
                answer = random.choice(dummy_sentences)

            print(answer)

mychatbot = simplechatbot()
mychatbot.run()
```

My actual result is:

```
Hi, what you want to talk about?
Hi
say something about it
I'm sick 
Why you are feeling sick?
```

I want to say something about my father ###### here the chatbot should ask about my father
    say something about it

Comment: I knew that before. And I have already mentioned in the title that how to add 2nd array for the "relation", I have added the code and my output so that people could understand what I wánted to do. And for the posted code "I have followed the coding style".  Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

There's a high-level problem that's blocking your functionality.  A debugging attempt would have caught this quickly.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

In particular, note the lines

```
    relation = ["father", "mother", "sister", "brother"]
    ...
        for feeling in feelings:
          for relation in relation:
```

At this point, you have wiped out your list of relations: the variable `relation` now refers only to the string "father".  The next time you hit this statement -- the second iteration of the `feelings` loop, you will iterate through the characters of `father`, assigning `relation = 'f'` and losing the rest.

I suggest that you treat the list of relations as you did with `feelings`:

```
    relations = ["father", "mother", "sister", "brother"]
    ...
        for feeling in feelings:
          for relation in relations:
```

Now we can get some progress.  Sample dialogue:

```
Hi, what you want to talk about?
I'm sick
Why you are feeling sick?
My father has the flu, and I think I might catch it.
("what's the name of your", 'father', '?')
```

This last "sentence" has a different format because you assigned the pieces as a tuple, rather than concatenating them.  Can you take it from here?